# JavaScript destructuring object containing fields with special characters

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I have array (API response):

```
let arr = [
    { '@type': 'Something', data: 1234 },
    { '@type': 'Something', data: 3214 },
]
```

Is it possible to destructure elements with those '@' prefixed fields?

```
for (const { data, ??? @type } of arr) {}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take a [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and a new variable name.

```js
let arr = [{ '@type': 'Something', data: 1234 }, { '@type': 'Something', data: 3214 }];

for (const { data, ['@type']: renamed } of arr) {
    console.log(renamed);
}
```

Comment: Thx! I tried with computed properties, but without renaming. Now it works!